# Electrical Engineering - Transformer

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, transformer, ac, impedance

A transformer of primary voltage 220 V and turns ratio of 11:1. The secondary of the transformer is connected to a 30 Ω inductive reluctance in series with a load resistance (R). If the current flowing in (R) must not be below 0.4 A. Then the value of (R) is:

The answer on my book is at most 40 Ω , but I found the answer to be at most 20 Ω

What is did is that , secondary voltage , which can be easily found by the turn ratio, is 20 V

Then, to find the current at the  secondary side we divide the secondary voltage = 20 V over the total resistance = 30 + R Ω

after doing the math R should be at most 20Ω for the current at the secondary side not to drop below .4 A

I don't know where is my mistake , Could someone explain to my what I have done wrong on this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

\$I >= 0.4 \$

i.e., \$V/Z >= 0.4\$

\$V = 20\$

\$Z =\sqrt{R^2 + X^2}\$, **NOT** \$(R+X)\$

Solve.

Answer (score 2):

You have added the reluctance and resistance, you can't do that. You have to calculate the impedance of the circuit.

Comment: I added them because they have the same unit , why not ?

Comment: @user34755 Same reason as 5+4i =! 9

Comment: They have the same units, but you know current and voltage have a 90 degree phase relationship in inductor, which is not there in resistor. That phase shift creates this squared relation , when calculating impedance. Refer to the vector diagram of series RL AC circuit.